# Why am I getting a false only in IE9 for image complete property?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, jquery-on

I've seen this pattern used quite a bit, but it seems IE9 doesn't like it. Here is a rough idea of what my function does:

```
function(path){
    $("<img/>",{"src":path}).one("load",function(event,alreadyLoaded) {
        if(!alreadyLoaded) { 
            myObject.loadedImages = myObject.loadedImages || [];
            myObject.loadedImages.push(this);
        }
    // Other code here...                   
    }).each(function() {
        if(this.complete) {
            $(this).trigger("load",true);
        }
    });
}
```

I realize this might be a duplicate, but the suggestions I've seen aren't working:
(e.g. this.readyState // returns uninitialized)

If someone could please point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: Why use `each` when you know there's only one image? I don't think it's related to your problem, just curious.

Comment: I don't understand what you are attempting here. You create an image element, assign a load event, but why are you trying to trigger it yourself? Wouldn't (or won't) it be triggered already by the browser itself?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder using `each` is just a way to chain an anonymous function to my current jQuery object assuring it **will** run. @RoToRa I'm not assigning `load`, I'm assinging `one`; the idea is that load should only run once per image. So when this image is created again load should not run, because the image is cached. The anonymous function still runs though and will trigger load with a parameter `alreadyLoaded` which keeps me from adding it to my object a second time, but still allows me to run `// Other code here` notifying other objects of this images 'readyness'... does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.one()` applies per element, not per `src` attribute or image file.  So, if you create two separate image elements and call `.one("load", ...)` on both of them, the load event will fire for both images, even though they share a source and the image file itself is cached.

To prevent duplicates in your array, use a hash instead:

```
function addImage (path) { 
    $("<img/>").load(function (e) { 
        myObject.loadedImages = myObject.loadedImages || {};
        if(!this.src in myObject.loadedImages) {  
            myObject.loadedImages[this.src] = this; 
        }
    }).attr({ "src": path });
}
```

Comment: **Very nice solution!** Oh, and yeah I realize I worded my comment on `.one()` poorly, that's what debugging IE at 2:00 am can do to a man... so thanks for straightening that out as well.

Comment: Please don't resent that I haven't checked this as the answer,...yet. I would actually like to know if/why the `complete` property is buggy. This does very nicely answer my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348017/how-to-tell-when-an-image-is-already-in-browser-cache-in-ie9/8348184#8348184) though. Other browsers won't fire the load event a second time though... so this still would have to used in conjunction with my `complete` property check.

Comment: @bodine - The `complete` property isn't really buggy, just inconsistent across browsers. IE doesn't set `complete` to true until it fires the `load` event. Actually, that's what I'd expect and I'm a little surprised the other browsers have `complete` set to true before firing the `load` event. At any rate, yes, the `load` event will fire for all browsers without triggering it explicitly, even when `complete == true`. Remember the `load` event is for the *element*, not the file (well, not *just* the file). This demo shows that load fires even for cached images: http://jsfiddle.net/JsbyT/1/

Comment: From the caveats listed on the [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) page, I get the impression it's a good idea to check it both ways, although I'm having trouble finding use cases that exhibit this inconsistency. Large images maybe... Either way it's a good point about the expectation one has for the `complete` property.

Comment: @bodine - That's an interesting read... And come to think of it, I remember reading it before.  I'd be interested to see a deeper discussion of it.  I would expect the difficulties come from changing the src on an existing image element, and that `load` would fire consistently for all new elements, but I could be wrong.  One important thing to do is to bind `load` before setting the `src`.  I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Since I can't edit my wording in the original question, and since this perfectly achieves what I needed to have done; you get the answer. Thanks for the help,... stack rules!