# How to tell when an image is already in browser cache in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

IE9 is showing false `complete` property with the following:

```
$("<img/>",{src:"http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1104/1434841504_edc671e65c.jpg"}).each(function(){console.log(this.complete);});
```

If you run this code in a browser console, (allow enough time for the image to load) then run it again. IE9 is the only browser I've tested showing false the second time. This seems to be a known bug, from some simple google searching. 
**I need a workaround if anyone has one.**

This could be a timing issue, as letting the code above set a global variable a la:

```
var img = $("<img....
```

and then testing that variable's properties gives different results:

```
img[0].complete === true
```

and

```
 img[0].readyState === "complete"
```

There must be some other way of getting this infomation. Any ideas... Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question [as the one you asked 11 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338770/why-am-i-getting-a-false-only-in-ie9-for-image-complete-property)?

Comment: @Xeon06 A subtle difference for sure, they other question seems to be worded such that it is asking about the bug itself. Here I'm asking for a workaround, plus the simplified code is maybe less confusing in this question.

Comment: `if( image.complete || image.readyState == "complete" )` is how you would test if its cached

Comment: checking `naturalWidth` or `naturalHeight` seem to return useful values... I'll test this more and answer if/when I can.

Comment: I got a loaded image whcih returns false for this.complete and undefined for naturalWidth. So I guess the readyState remains that is set to true.

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
function doWhenLoaded(obj,callback) {

if($.browser.msie) {
    var src=$(obj).attr("src");
    $(obj).attr("src","");
    $(obj).attr("src",src);
}

$(obj).one("load",callback).each(function(){
    // alert(this.readyState+" "+this.src);
    if(
        this.complete
        || this.readyState == "complete"
        || this.readyState == 4
        || ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) == 6)
    ) {
        $(this).trigger("load");
    }
}); 
}
```

A sample:

```
doWhenLoaded("#main_background_img",function(){
    $("#main_background_img").slideDown(1000);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i usually preload an image:

```
var img = new Image();
$(img).attr('src', "foo.jpg");
if (img.complete || img.readyState === 4) {
    // image is cached
    alert("the image was cached!");
} else {
    $(img).load(function() {
        // image was not cached, but done loading
        alert("the image was not cached, but it is done loading.");
    });
}
```

I haven't deeply debugged it in IE9, but I haven't ran into any issues with it.

the code was pulled from https://github.com/tentonaxe/jQuery-preloadImages/blob/master/jquery.preloadimages.js and modified.

Comment: Run that code in IE9, with an actual image, and you'll be loading it everytime. The code posted in my question is part of a larger block that looks similar to what you post here. See my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338770/why-am-i-getting-a-false-only-in-ie9-for-image-complete-property)

Comment: Good to know, i'll have to look deeper into it at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an AJAX request on the image and see the status code. If it's 304 it means the image was cached. Not sure how well that would work though. Maybe AJAX does some cache-busting.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a million years ago, but I figure I would contribute my solution which is similar but has less overhead and i/o.

Basically, you create a custom jQuery method that performs the similar feats all in one function:

```
$.fn.imgLoad = function(callback) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if(callback){
            if(this.complete || (this.readyState === 4) || (this.readyState === 'complete')) {
                callback.apply(this);
            } else {
                $(this).one('load.imgCallback', function(){
                    callback.apply(this);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This consolidates the checking of all possible events into one (both cached and uncached), but also makes the method chainable. You can call it with:

```
$('img').imgLoad(function(){
    console.log('loaded');
});
```

Works cross-browser, back to IE6. Notice it checks for caching first, and if not triggers a namespaced load event only once to prevent reloads in case you call the function with that logic twice, but also to allow custom load events to be bound (if applicable).

Answer (score -2):

You can't tell if it's cached, but you can force a fresh load by "salting" the filename:

```
src:"http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1104/1434841504_edc671e65c.jpg?"+new Date()
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to reload the image, that's the point. The load event only fires once, after that if I try to build this image again it should find it in the browser cache.